# RESTful API return conventions

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I'm still learning c# web API at the moment, and I've faced some problems.

so the code snippet below shows a portion of my codes that will create a new student in the database, what I am trying to do is to create the object and if it succeeded, it will return a HTTP-CREATED http response code and return the STUDENT OBJECT.

if it fails, it should return a HTTP-BADREQUEST response code and ALSO return the STUDENT OBJECT.

HOWEVER, in order to return the response code, I am unable to return a student object and vice-versa due to the return type set, hence, the dilemma.

```
// POST api/student
        public HttpResponseMessage PostStudent(Models.Student student)
        {
            if (DBManager.createStudent(student) != null)
                return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Created);
                // HOW TO RETURN STUDENT OBJECT?
            else
                return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
                // HOW TO RETURN STUDENT OBJECT?
        }
```

Comment: What is the point of returning the Student object if the operation fails? I'm learning Web API too.

Comment: this is just an example. there could be scenarios where you need to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`HttpRequestMessageExtensions.CreateResponse<T> Method`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh969014%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) has an optional formal paramater called `value` that can be used to create an `HttpResponseMessage` that contains both a status code and an object.

```
return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, student);
```

Answer (score -3):

I'll tell you my own experience of building a web server for my company: DON'T use WebApi. There are so many limitations and in short, supports a very narrow usage scenario. Just stick to the traditional MVC controllers and life is much easier:

```
public ActionResult PostStudent(Models.Student s){
    //do something
    Response.StatusCode = 400;
    return Json(s);
}
```